# Activity Tab For Stack Exchange users is sometimes empty

Tags: bug, recent-activity, network-profile

For some users, the activity tab is empty ("no activity found") if "all" is selected, even though the tabs other than "all" are non-empty.  Also, the "all" tab is loading much slower than usual for the users with an empty "all" tab.

As of now:
https://stackexchange.com/users/9777/brian?tab=activity - Empty
https://stackexchange.com/users/32093/eric-lippert?tab=activity - Empty
https://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet?tab=activity - Working normally

Comment: Hey, me too! :( http://stackexchange.com/users/1000547/miketheliar?tab=activity

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: I figured Jon Skeet would be the canonical example of an activity tab that should not be empty, but of course **his** activity tab is working.

Comment: Jon Skeet never stops working.

Comment: When Jon Skeet's activity tab is empty we've reached the heat-death of the Universe. You could iterate of all possible GUIDs before Jon Skeet's activity tab was empty.

Comment: This issue hasn't been happening lately.  Based on the way the activity page performed (specifically, the slow response time when repeatedly switching back and forth between a broken "all" tab and an "accepts" tab, my suspicion is that a query was somehow failing, possibly by timing out.  I have no clue if this remains an issue (though if it's still a bug, it's one that *currently* has no impact).