# "Activity" tab for the Community user's network profile sometimes leads to a server error

Tags: bug, community-user, network-profile, 500-server-error

If I try to view [the "Activity" tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity) in the [Community user's profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) on stackexchange.com, the page loads for about 15 seconds, and then I get an "Oops, something bad happened" page. Note that this *only happens sometimes*.

This is somewhat similar to [Activity Tab For Stack Exchange users is sometimes empty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224402/activity-tab-for-stackexchange-users-is-sometimes-empty), except that in this case, I get an error page.

Can this be fixed, so that I can always view the Community user's activity?

Comment: I find that the Activity tab for the Community User's Network Profile  **always** results in an error, I figured that it simply resulted in too many queries across so many sites that it couldn't complete within a reasonable time; surprised that this hasn't received more attention.

Comment: Is this even possible, without faster and stronger soft/hardware?  Given Community's function, the server has a colossal amount of stuff to load from all across the network.  I'm not surprised it does this.